# Why is my res.send({message:"Hi"}); showing Error: node_redis: The SET command contains a invalid argument type error?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I have a trouble something which I cannot understand absolutely.

I send such fetch request from React to Expressjs server

```
    fetch('//localhost:8000/auth/checkLoginStatus',{
    method:'GET',
    credentials:'include',
    headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
}).then((data)=>{
    return data.json();
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data).length);
    if(JSON.stringify(data)[0]){
        debugger;
    }   
});
```

So as you see in fetch URL, I send a request to *'localhost:8000/auth/checkLoginStatus'*

This is my main express.js code

```
//main javascript file for nodejs. server

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors =require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const chatRouter = require('./router/chatRouter.js');
const authRouter = require('./router/authRouter.js');
const redis = require ('./redis/redis');
const { RedisClient } = require('redis');
const redisStore= require('connect-redis')(session);
require('dotenv').config();
//cors setting
app.use(cors({
  origin:'http://localhost:8081',
  credentials:true
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
//redis
const createdClientRedis = redis.createRedisClient();
app.use(
  session({
    resave:false,
    name:'user',
    saveUninitialized:true,
    secret:process.env.redis_secret_key,
    cookie:{
      httpOnly:true,
      secure:false
    },
    store:new RedisClient({createdClientRedis})
  })
);

//Routers
app.use('/chat',chatRouter);
app.use('/auth',authRouter);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

With router, my request will be handled in authRouter. And code below is code in authRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dbFile = require('../userListDB');
const cookie = require('../cookie-session/cookie');
const redis = require('../redis/redis.js');
router.use(express.json());

//if login POST request is sent from client
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    dbFile.checkIfUserExists(req.body.userId,'login')
    .then(()=>{
        return dbFile.loginSQL(req);
      }).then((data)=>{
        return dbFile.comparePWtoEncryptedPassword(data);
      }).then((data)=>{
        redis.setRedis(req);
        res.send({
          errorMessage:''
        });
      })
      .catch((errMessage)=>{
        dbFile.sendDBError(res,errMessage);
      })
});

router.get("/checkLogInStatus",(req,res)=>{
  console.log("cookie "+req.cookies['user']);
  console.log("session "+req.session.id);
  res.send({message:"hi"});
});
router.post("/signOut",(req,res)=>{
  return new Promise((resolve,rejct)=>{
    redis.removeDataFromRedis(req);
    resolve(res);
  })
  .then((res)=>{
    cookie.removeCookie(res);
    return res;
  })
  .then(res=>{
    res.status(200).send("signed out");
  })
})
//if register POST request sent from client
router.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  const userPw = req.body.userPW;
  const userFirstName = req.body.userFirstName;
  const userAfterName = req.body.userAfterName;
  const userPwConfirm = req.body.pwConfirm;
  try{
    if(/\d/.test(userFirstName)||/\d/.test(userAfterName)){
      throw "First name and after name shouldn't contain number";
    }
    if(userId.length<5&&userPw.length<5){
      throw "Id and password must be minimum 5 characters";
    }else if(userId.length>=5&&userPw.length<5){
      throw "Password must be minimum 5 characters";
    }else if(userId.length<5&&userPw.length>=5){
      throw "Id must be minimum 5 characters";
    }
    if(userPw!=userPwConfirm){
      throw "Password confirmation wrong";
    }else{
      dbFile.checkIfUserExists(userId,'register')
      .then((response)=>{
        return dbFile.registerNewUser(req.body);
      }).then((data)=>{
        res.send({
          errorMessage:''
        })
      }).catch((errMessage)=>{
        console.log(errMessage);
        dbFile.sendDBError(res,errMessage);
      });
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    dbFile.sendDBError(res,e);
  }
});
module.exports=router;
```

Problem is in router.get('/checkLoginStatus').
res.send inside function throws such errors:

> Error: node_redis: The SET command contains a invalid argument type.
> Only strings, dates and buffers are accepted. Please update your code to use valid argument types.

```
at RedisClient.internal_send_command (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/redis/index.js:835:39)
at RedisClient.set (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/redis/lib/commands.js:46:25)    at Session.save (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express-session/session/session.js:72:25)
at Session.save (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express-session/index.js:406:15)
at ServerResponse.end (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express-session/index.js:335:21)
at ServerResponse.send (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10)
at ServerResponse.json (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
at router.get (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/src/router/authRouter.js:29:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ReactFromScratch/chatting-app/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

authRouter.js29:7 is equal to res.send().
Of course if I remove the code line, the error is gone.

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

This is my redis code. I think this is redis which is causing problem because error message shows something about RedisClient too.

```
//file which is used to control redis database

const redis = require('redis');
let redisClient
module.exports={
    //app.js 에서 사용 
    createRedisClient:function(){
        redisClient = redis.createClient({
            host:"127.0.0.1",
            port:"6379",
            db:0
        });
        redisClient.on('error',function(err){
            console.log('Redis Error :'+err);
        });
    },
    //authRouter.js에서 사용
    setRedis:function(req){
        redisClient.set(req.sessionID,req.body.userId);
    },
    getRedis:function(req){
        console.log("get redis");
        redisClient.get(req.sessionID,function(err,value){
            console.log("redis returned :"+value);
        });
    },
    removeDataFromRedis:function(req){
        redisClient.flushall();//just for debugging...
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Main JavaScript file for Node.JS server

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors =require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const chatRouter = require('./router/chatRouter.js');
const authRouter = require('./router/authRouter.js');
const redis = require('./redis/redis');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
require('dotenv').config();
// cors setting
app.use(cors({
  origin:'http://localhost:8081',
  credentials:true
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
// redis
app.use(
  session({
    resave:false,
    name:'user',
    saveUninitialized:true,
    secret:process.env.redis_secret_key,
    cookie:{
      httpOnly:true,
      secure:false
    },
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redis.createRedisClient() }) // !
  })
);
// Routers
app.use('/chat',chatRouter);
app.use('/auth',authRouter);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```